# ActionScript reference to grandchild (child of child) element

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, mxml, grandchild

Let's say I have some basic MXML setup as follows:

```
<Item id="parent">
    <Frame>
        <mx:Image/>
    </Frame>
</Item>
```

How can I refer to an attribute of the Image element by referring to it as a grandchild (child of a child) of the parent Item? I've tried daisy-chaining two calls to getChildAt(), i.e.:

```
parent.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildAt through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

What is the proper way to make a call to a grandchild element?

Comment: You might have to cast it as a `MovieClip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getChildAt()` function returns a DisplayObject

[getChildAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt%28%29)

So you must be type cast as follows.

```
DisplayObjectContainer(parent.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great, and now I understand what that error means. ;-)